# boolean variable being returned by UDF is not recognized by stock Excel OR function

Tags: vba, excel, boolean, excel-2007

Alright, I have written a UDF, which searches a given cell for a specific sub-string. 
It then returns TRUE is the sub-string is found in the cell, and FALSE if it is not found.

Here is the code for the UDF (named the `contains` function)

```
Function contains(substring As String, testString As String) As String
'testString = cell to be tested for substring
Dim result As Boolean
result = False
testString = UCase(testString)
substring = UCase(substring)

For i = 1 To Len(testString)
If Mid(testString, i, Len(substring)) = substring Then result = True
Next

contains = result

End Function
```

The reason I created this function is so that I can nest it within stock Excel functions, mainly `IF` functions, `AND` functionS, and `OR` functions.

However, when I use it with an OR function, the OR function does not seem to "recognize" the result of the =contains function.

Here is a screenshot of the issue within Excel:
[image: containsprobelem]

*EDIT* Here is what the =contains function is doing in the above pic `=contains("Hello",A2)`

Obviously, since the =Contains function in column C is returning `True`, then the `OR` function in column D should be returning `True` as well. But for some reason it is as if the stock Excel `OR` function doesn't recognize the result of my `contains` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the function return a `boolean`:

```
Function contains(substring As String, testString As String) As boolean
```

Not sure why you are looping as you are, you can just use:

```
contains = InStr(1, testString, substring, vbTextCompare) > 0
```

Comment: Awesome! Now that I modified the function to return a Boolean it works just fine. I was originally under the impression that the function *was* returning a Boolean, since the function is returning the variable `result` which is of type `Boolean`.

Comment: It's the `as` in the function declaration that determines the final type,

Comment: And I used a loop because I wasn't aware of the `InStr` functions existence, but I will remember it for the future.

Comment: @AdamJ instead of a UDF wrapper you could consider using `=FIND()` which is kind of equivalent to `InStr()`

Comment: Thanks, I have used that previously, in order to test a cell for a string, but I like my UDF because it returns a Boolean and it's easy to nest within IF functions. –